# URQL: Union type field in an un-keyable entity gets wrong typename from the union

Tags: graphql, codegen, urql

So I have this fragment

```
fragment fullOption on Option {
  selectId
  type
  options {
    ... on NumberArray {
      values
    }
    ... on CustomNumberArray {
      id
      name
      values
    }
  }
}
```

All of the `Option`, `NumberArray` and `CustomNumberArray` are un-keyable entities.

Invalidating the `Option` field is obviously overcoming this issue in the context of Mutations, but I have this problem occurring with the Queries where even though the API data has the correct typenames for the respective options, the URQL Cache client messes that data and there is some option that is `NumberArray` but it gets treated as `CustomNumberArray`.

Has anyone met with a similar issue?

Tried adding __typename in the fragment definitions, and resolver __typename enforcing is also "illegal", so I wasn't sure about any other possible solutions.